# Adding line break in javascript after the occurrences a field in an array

Tags: javascript, html

So I am using an api for air pollution index and I am trying to add a line break after each state (stated in title field in variable state). After trying multiple way actually I am not getting the desired output.

```
var states = [
    {
        title: "Wilayah Persekutuan",
        cities: [
            "kuala-lumpur",
            "malaysia/w.p.-putrajaya/putrajaya",
            "malaysia/wilayah-persekutuan/labuan",
        ]
    },
    {
        title: "Perak",
        cities: [
            "ipoh",
            "malaysia/perak/tanjung-malim"
        ]
    },
    ...
];

var aqiWidgetConfig = [];
var multipleCityAqiElement = document.getElementById('multiple-city-aqi');

states.forEach(function(state, index) {
    var cities = state.cities;
    var stateTitle = state.title;

    cities.forEach(function(city) {
        aqiWidgetConfig.push({
            city: city,
            callback: function(aqi) {
                displayCity(aqi, stateTitle);
            }
        });
    });
});

_aqiFeed(aqiWidgetConfig);

function displayCity(aqi, stateTitle) {
    var cityAqiWidget = document.createElement('div');
    cityAqiWidget.className = 'city-aqi-widget';
    cityAqiWidget.innerHTML = '<h2>' + stateTitle + '</h2>' + aqi.text("%details<br><br>");
    multipleCityAqiElement.appendChild(cityAqiWidget);

    // Add line break before every different value of stateTitle
    if (stateTitle !== states[0].title) {
        var lineBreak = document.createElement('div');
        lineBreak.style.clear = 'both';
        multipleCityAqiElement.appendChild(lineBreak);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using <br> in document.createElement("br"); ??

Comment: Yes, that doesnt seem to work

Comment: what is the error did you face ?? Any error message?